# How to disable sftp access to user with ssh already disabled (user shell = /bin/false, but connection still works with sftp)

Tags: ssh, sftp

In `sshd_config`, by default, login is allowed for all groups and users. The allow/deny directives are processed in the following order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups. (found in the man page).

So, I have to configure the server in a "blacklist way" (all are allowed, then I explicitely define whom access can be denied).

Is there a way to do the opposite ? I want if a user can't connect to ssh, the sftp connection will be refused, except if he match a rule.

I set the default shell to `/bin/false` (so classic ssh connection is disabled).

Locking the user (`usermod -L usersftp1`) obviously prevent the user to use both sftp and ssh (which is fine for me).

I tried to use `DenyGroups !sftp` directive to disallow user matching other than sftp but the usersftp1 (which does not belongs to the group sftp (primary nor supplementary) but it didn't work.

---

I configured my server to manage some sftp access (starting with `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`)

In /etc/passwd, the line `usersftp1:x:5001:5001::/home/sftp/usersftp1:/bin/false`

The ssh connection doesn't work (which is what I want), but I can connect through sftp (beside the fact I didn't allowed that user yet).

I want the default behavior to be "connection not allowed" if user has the `/bin/false` shell.

EDIT: more configuration details:

```
file /etc/passwd:
    usersftp1:x:50001:5001::/home/sftp/usersftp1:/bin/false
file /etc/group:
    usersftp1:x:5001

file /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
    …
    Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -l INFO
    # This is commented, so no rules will be set for user "usersftp1"
    #   Match user usersftp1
    #   X11Forwarding no
    #   ChrootDirectory %h
    #   AllowTcpForwarding no
    #   ForceCommand internal-sftp  

      # This config works as expected
      Match user usersftp2
      X11Forwarding no
      ChrootDirectory %h
      AllowTcpForwarding no
      ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

in `auth.log`, I can see the user uses sftp :

`Starting session: subsystem 'sftp' for usersftp1 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 55552`

In that configuration, after `service ssh restart`, users `usersftp1` and `usersftp2` can both connect using sftp (beside the fact the 1st one is commented)

Comment: Is `/bin/false` presented in your `/etc/shells` file?

Comment: Yes the line is present

Comment: Remove it and try again.

Comment: almost the same result: I still can connect with sftp, but now the connection directory is the user home

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Match User is working in the way that you think it is.

> **Match**
>   Introduces a conditional block. If all of the criteria on the Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file, until either another Match line or the end of the file. If a keyword appears in multiple Match blocks that are satisfied, only the first instance of the keyword is applied.

So in your particular case the *Match User usersftp2* only applies to and overrides the configuration for usersftp2.

When your usersftp1 connects, the sftp program is run for them by sshd and no user specific configurations are applied.

---

If I understand your question correctly you should be able to do what you want with a group.

create a group e.g. sftpusers (groupadd...) and then add the users you want to allow to it (usermod -G ...)

Then configure sshd to only allow sftp for users in that group

```
Match Group sftpusers
  # Force the connection to use SFTP
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  # Disable tunneling, authentication agent, TCP and X11 forwarding.
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

Comment: My problem is than the user can log in when it shouldn't. . The configuration is commented, so the user should not be able to connect, as his shell is `/bin/false`